# xampp for an android or ipad ? Maybe on USB key?

Tags: android, ipad, apache, xampp, tablet

In order to do some demos of a web app to my prospects, I want to use a tablet and no internet connexion, just a local apache server. For the moment, I have none but I'm going to buy one, maybe on Android or an Ipad.

I saw there is some portable versions of a XAMPP environment that are working on a USB key.

I want to know if it's possible to use such a server on an Ipad or an Android tablet? For android, do I have to use a LAMP environment?

EDIT : to precise, I'm searching something like these servers : http://www.uwamp.com/ or http://www.server2go-web.de which are working for windows (I'm going to think to buy a MS surface...)

Thanks for your reply

Bastien

Comment: Is a mobile Internet connection - maybe with a prepaid SIM card - totally out of the question? You'd have to test the connectivity at your client's location but it might be much less hassle than running a web server... on the other hand, having the web server in your pocket is much more reliable, of course

Comment: Thanks for answer. Of course I can use a SIM card with 3G connexion but I just want to know of there is an alternative solution possible with a local server. More reliable than the internet 3G connexion and free :).

Answer (score -1):

Somebody told me about KS Web, an android app. Not tested. But seems not to manage innoDB.

Bastien